# Python a = a.reverse makes the list empty?

Tags: python

At the interpreter,

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a = a.reverse()
```

Next when I type a at the interpreter, I get nothing. So it seems a = a.reverse() generates an empty list. Is this by design?

I am using python 2.5 on windows xp.

Comment: Documentation here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists and here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Answer (score 18, accepted):

list.reverse() modifies the list in-place, returns None. But if you want to protect old list, you can use reversed() function for that, it returns an iterator.

```
In [1]: a=[1,2,3,4]

In [2]: print(a.reverse())
None

In [3]: a
Out[3]: [4, 3, 2, 1]

In [4]: a=[1,2,3,4]

In [5]: print(reversed(a))
<listreverseiterator object at 0x24e7e50>

In [6]: list(reversed(a))
Out[6]: [4, 3, 2, 1]

In [7]: a
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

`reverse` changes list in-place, and doesn't return anything. Thus, this is the expected usage:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.reverse()
a       # => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you assign the result of `reverse` back to `a`, you will overwrite all its hard work with the nonsensical return value (`None`), which is where your bug comes from.

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a mutable type, so `list` operations are in-place, and return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in method `reverse` of a list on python doesn't return the reversed list.

It reverses the list in place.

So, if you want to reverse your list, like in your code, just do:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.reverse()` just doesn't return anything, because it changes the list in-place. See this example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

There also is the `reversed` function (actually a type, but doesn't matter here), which does not change the list in-place, but instead returns an iterator with the list items in the reverse order. Try:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a = list(reversed(a))
>>> a
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.reverse()
```

`a` is an object and the operations work on it's data, so you don't need to assign again it.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse method does the reverse 'in place' (like sort) and returns None, so after calling `a.reverse()` `a` already contains the result.